# IE loads sometimes WOFF and sometimes EOT font type

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-11, google-material-icons

I use Angular Material with Angular Material Icon. 
In my index.html, I have the following tag :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

This line downloads a CSS file with a @font-face selector. It seems the "src" property coming from the CSS is different according the browser.

With Chrome, no issue, it downloads a WOFF2 font. But on IE11, sometimes the browser downloads a WOFF font and sometimes, a EOT font. With WOFF, icons are displayed. With EOT, they aren't.

[image: Chrome logs]

[image: IE11 logs]

Do you have an idea how to force browser to download WOFF font? I would like to avoid to store font-face locally.

Thank you !

Comment: Is the font you want to use available in woff?

Comment: Of course since sometimes IE downloads it as WOFF type and icon is thus displayed.
Font is Material Icon from Google.

IE downloads it as WOFF especially when I have Fiddler open...

Comment: So you are saying sometimes *the same font* is downloaded as woff and other times it's downloaded as eot?

Comment: Yes @Rob ! That's exactly what I say.

Comment: perhaps an odd question, but: why are you even offering `eot` at all? That's a dead format that was only supported by IE8 and below, which Microsoft hard-discontinued almost two years ago.

Comment: I don't offer eot type. The call to https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons sends to IE11 a css with sometimes EOT, sometimes WOFF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have finally changed the way to use Material Icon font.

I deleted the following line in my index.html file :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

I installed **material-design-icons** package via NPM and I configured the *styles* section of my **angular-cli.json** file to point on the css file like this :

```
"styles": [
    "<relative_path>/node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
]
```

Now, IE11 always loads WOFF type.

Problem solved!